# Как правильно прописать код JS для меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите пожалуйста как правильно прописать js для меню? Есть две кнопки `"Материалы"` и `"Кнопка бургера"`, которая появляется только при мобильной версии. По клику на материалы, все прекрасно работает, но когда нажимаешь на бургер, меню открывается и пропадает. Как решить эту проблему? Код ниже

```js
$(function() {
    var res = $(".header__menu");
    $(".menu-click").on("click", funk);
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('menu-click')) funk(false);
    });

    $('.header__menu').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation() });

    function funk(flag) {
        if (res.css("display") == "none" && flag) {
            res.fadeIn(300);
        } else {
            res.fadeOut(300);
        }
    }
});

$(function() {
    var resS = $(".header__menu");
    $(".burger-click").on("click", funkS);
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$(e.target).hasClass('burger-click')) funkS(false);
    });

    $('.header__menu').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation() });

    function funkS(flagS) {
        if (resS.css("display") == "none" && flagS) {
            resS.fadeIn(300);
        } else {
            res.fadeOut(300);
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.header__list--item {
  padding: 18px 32px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-click {
  padding: 18px 32px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__menu {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  padding: 52px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header__list--item menu-click">Материалы</div>
  <div class="header__list--item burger-click">Бургер</div>
</div>

 <div class="header__menu">
    Контетн
  </div>
```

Comment: Подскажите что должно делать строка `$(document).click(function(e) {...}`? Вы на одни и те же элементы вешаете по два события

Comment: По клику на кнопку с классом "menu-click" должно открыть меню .header__menu

Comment: У вас по два события на `".header__menu"`, `$(document)` и судя по коду вы не совсем понимаете что вы делаете. Попробуйте написать на чистом js и не будет возникать вопросов таких, вы тогда поймете что означает `$(function() {});` зачем так писать и когда так не желательно писать. Почему вы после строки `var res = $(".header__menu");` пишите `$('.header__menu').on('click',...)` почему вы в одном месте используете `.on` в другом `.click`, jquery не рекомендует давно использовать `.click` это у них на сайте написано. Код собран с разных постов stackoverflow

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать как правильно должно быть?

Comment: Посмотрите на ответ, это то что Вам нужно было?

Comment: Автор, а зачем вы создаёте разные аккаунты и задаёте одни и теже вопросы?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1303502/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%83

Comment: @Макск может тестовое на собеседование или домашка))

Comment: Ну главное, чтобы человек разобрался, в итоге )

Answer (score 1):

Идея создать функцию которая с методами `открыть` и `закрыть` и вызывать открытие где угодно на странице

В качестве проверки открыто меню или закрыто я использую булевую переменную `isOpened` и при нажатии на кнопку вызываю метод `.show()` или `.hide()`

Запись 
`showHideMenu.isOpened?showHideMenu.hide():showHideMenu.show()`
это сокращение от записи

```
if(showHideMenu.isOpened){
  showHideMenu.hide()
}else{
  showHideMenu.show()
}
```

Сокращение имеет вид `(условие)?если истина:если ложь` при этом такая запись обязательно должна содержать условие если ложь

```js
let showHideMenu = {
  isOpened: false,
  menu: $(".header__menu"),
  show(){
    this.isOpened = true
    this.menu.fadeIn(300)
  },
  hide(){
    this.isOpened = false
    this.menu.fadeOut(300)
  }
}

$(".menu-click, .burger-click").on('click', ()=>{
  showHideMenu.isOpened?showHideMenu.hide():showHideMenu.show()
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.header__list--item {
  padding: 18px 32px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-click {
  padding: 18px 32px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__menu {
  display: none;
  background: red;
  padding: 52px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header__list--item menu-click">Материалы</div>
  <div class="header__list--item burger-click">Бургер</div>
</div>

 <div class="header__menu">
    Контетн
  </div>
```

Comment: Кажись у вас ошибка в самом первом коде. И вместо ```if (isOpened ){ showHideMenu.show } else { showHideMenu.hide }``` можно использовать ```showHideMenu.toggle(isOpened)```.

Comment: Проверил код - ошибку не нашел, уточните пожалуйста. Если написать `showHideMenu.toggle(isOpened)` это вообще работать не будет, и нет в этой записи смысла. Переписать по аналогии с ответом HTO HOT можно, без css и скорее получится тоже в одну строку (как я предлагал в комментарии у HTO HOT), но я специально написал в виде функции, чтоб автор разбирался и смотрел что можно по-разному решать одну и ту же задачу.

Comment: "это сокращение от записи" и дальше кусочек кода. И почему же .toggle работать не будет?

Comment: Кхм.. Понял, что вы использовали не метод jQ для показа и скрытия.

Comment: укажите на ошибку, туплую.  ...я пока писал понял что вы имели ввиду)) вот так будет работать:`$(".header__menu").toggle()` Только никак не получается сделать через  [.toggle( display )](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) и тогда код еще в два раза сократится)

Comment: У вас написано: ```if(showHideMenu.isOpened){
  showHideMenu.show(
}else{
  showHideMenu.show()
}```. Ошибки: 1 - не закрыта скобка у метода, 2 - второй метод тоже show, вместо hide. .toggle принимает булевую переменную, хотя вы наверное это поняли и имеете не ввиду не это. В целом вариант с .toggle тут не катит ибо используется fadeIn/Out.

Comment: Спаисбо, в упор не видел ошибку. toggle display я понял что булевую у меня как раз `showHideMenu.isOpened` такова, но что бы я не пробовал `.toggle(true)`, `.toggle({display: true})` работать не хоче, в документации примеров не нашел

Comment: В самом конце есть пример. А так же после картинки с подписью "Figure 2", описано как это работает.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127369/discussion-between-greg-and-oliver-patterson).

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот довольно простой код ,для новичка думаю сойдёт

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
    let $content = $('.header__menu');
    let $menuClick = $('.menu-click');
    let $burger = $('.burger-click');
    $content.on('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation() });
    $burger.on('click',menuToggle);
    $menuClick.on('click',menuToggle);
    function menuToggle(){
      $content.toggleClass('active');
    }
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.header__list--item {
  padding: 18px 32px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger-click {
  padding: 18px 32px;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header__menu {
  
  
  background: red;
  padding: 52px 18px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  /*Вставил свой код*/
  visibility:hidden;
  opacity:0;
  transition:opacity 300ms, visibility 0ms 300ms;
}

/*Вставил свой код*/
.active.header__menu {
     transition:opacity 300ms, visibility 0ms 0ms;
     visibility:visible;
     opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header__list--item menu-click">Материалы</div>
  <div class="header__list--item burger-click">Бургер</div>
</div>

 <div class="header__menu">
    Контетн
  </div>
```

Comment: А что делает эта строка: `$content.on('click', function(e){e.stopPropagation() });` Вариант интересный но его можно было написать в одну строку: `$(document).ready(()=>{$('.menu-click, .burger-click').on('click', ()=>{$('.header__menu').toggleClass('active')` остальное не понимаю зачем нужно